# CSS Applied incorrectly?

Tags: html, css

I am using Firefox 25. But it also happens in IE7/8

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="elemento">
  <div class="form">
     <label for="formulario"> <span>Formulario:</span> </label>
     </div>
     <select id="formulario" name="formulario" class="select">
       <option value="Contratos - Literario">Contratos - Literario</option><option value="Inscripcion de obra publicada">Inscripcion de obra publicada</option>
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have this CSS being applied, says Firebug:

```
div.box .select {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    border-color: #171717;
    border-style: double;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 180px;
}
.acciones_botonera input, select {
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    border: medium none;
    color: #114477;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Why is the second CSS specially, being applied? `.acciones_botonera input, select` am I not saying here that only apply it to `select` elements that are INSIDE an element that has applied a class `.acciones_botonera`?

Comment: Jorge, what you're doing is applying to every input inside the .acciones_botonera container and then, also to every single select on the site. I don't exactly understand the results you want, why don't you tell us a bit about it?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.acciones_botonera input, select {

}
```

Will apply everything between the curly braces to all inputs inside elements that have the class '.acciones_botonera' as well as ALL selects in the DOM.

If you actually wanted to achieve the case you described it should look something like this:

```
.acciones_botonera input, .acciones_botonera select {

}
```